# Kendo DatePicker hide using user role

Tags: kendo-ui

I have date picker in form I need to disable for some user role lets say make invisible for readonly and visible for other.

```
var date = $("#dateofhistory");
date.kendoTestBox({
  mask: "00/00/0000",
  format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enable` property to enable/disable the DatePicker.

To Enable:

```
<script>
    $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").enable();
</script>
```

To Disable:

```
<script>
    $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").enable(false);
</script>
```

Be sure to look at Telerik's documentation [here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/api) for more information. Telerik has demo's for all of their controls and they are definitely worth looking at.